# Ogre no toma los materiales correctamente

Tags: game, blender, material, ogre

en blender he realizado un modelo con varias texturas para dar el efecto de profundidad (versión de blender 2.69) y luego exporte (exportador de ogre versión 0.6.0), pero cuando lo cargo en ogre se carga muy mal, no se combina bien los materiales, por lo que me queda el suelo totalmente oscuro.

```
material grass 
{
    receive_shadows on 

    technique
    {
        pass grass
        {
            ambient 0.800000011920929 0.800000011920929 0.800000011920929 1.0
            diffuse 0.6400000190734865 0.6400000190734865 0.6400000190734865 1.0
            specular 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0 12.5
            emissive 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0

            alpha_to_coverage off
            colour_write on
            cull_hardware clockwise
            depth_check on
            depth_func less_equal
            depth_write on
            illumination_stage 
            light_clip_planes off
            light_scissor off
            lighting on
            normalise_normals off
            polygon_mode solid
            scene_blend one zero
            scene_blend_op add
            shading gouraud
            transparent_sorting on

            texture_unit 
            {
                texture Grass-Short.jpg
                tex_address_mode wrap
                scale 0.025 0.025
                colour_op modulate
            }
            texture_unit 
            {
                texture Grass-Short_n.jpg
                tex_address_mode wrap
                scale 0.025 0.025
                colour_op modulate
            }
            texture_unit 
            {
                texture Grass-Short_s.jpg
                tex_address_mode wrap
                scale 0.025 0.025
                colour_op modulate
            }
```

Creo que la clave esta en las lineas:

```
   1- colour_op 
   2- tex_address_mode wrap
```

He intentado con otros colour_op, "alpha_blend", "modulate", "replace", "add", también combinando muchos de ellos y nada, lo mas aceptable que he conseguido es dejar la textura principal, pero le quita mucho realismo.

Agradecería la ayuda de cualquier alma humilde que haya en este foro :D :D[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

Aquí el resultado: arboles sin alfa, el suelo esta super mal, debería ser verde. Omitir el arma porque es un modelo beta
[image: 4]

Comment: usas [esto](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Blender+2.5+Exporter) ????

Comment: Desgraciadamente si, por suerte me falta el ultimo proyecto y nunca mas en la vida voy a tocar Ogre.

Comment: En este equipo no tengo blender instalado, deberia haber unas opciones de configuración cuado das exportar, podrias agregar la captura de pantalla

Comment: Claro, en este momento estoy subiendo :)

Comment: Joder, recién entiendo. No, usamos otro exportador versión 0.6.0 https://code.google.com/archive/p/blender2ogre/downloads

Comment: Si quitas Separate Materials y Export Select Only. Por otro lado, usar esqueleto en tu modelo?

Comment: Justamente este modelo no tiene porque es el mapa, pero todos los otros si porque son armas o personajes

Comment: Y podrias capturar un resultado de como se presenta el material importado

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y solo me exporta las texturas, nada mas!!!

Comment: Dale, ahora en dos minutos subo una captura del resultado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59335/discussion-between-strelok-and-jasilva).

Comment: Estoy en el chat nuevamente